# How to create autoincrement variable Odoo POS

Tags: odoo-10

I'm working on these files to add a custom autoincrement value to each pos ticket generated in odoo v10:

Point_of_sale es el modulo

.. \addons\point_of_sale\static\src\js\ models.js

.. \addons\pos_ticket\static\src\xml\pos_ticket_view.xml
odoo code:

```
Model.js
order_id_ : function (){
                var x = 1;        
                if(this.pos.order.id)
                    {
                        x = this.pos.order.id++;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        x = x++;
                    }
            function sequense(num)
                {
                    var s = ""+ num;
                    while (s.length < 8)
                    {
                        s = "0" + s;
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            return sequense(x);
        },
pos_ticket_view.xml
<t t-esc="order.order_id_()" / >
```

But when I run it like this I get this error because the variable isn't yet created:
[image: Only the first time]

Comment: You can refer code of order id generation. It is auto increment after every order paid.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement can't be processed if one of the earlier variables don't exist.

Instead of:

```
if(this.pos.order.id)
```

You should ensure the early variables exist, like so:

```
if(this.pos && this.pos.order && this.pos.order.id)
```

If `pos` or `pos.order` is not set, it should stop evaluating the if statement and you should no longer receive an error.